# where is com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm following the tutorial on GCM here http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

At point 5 of **Step 2**, it says:

> Add the following intent service:
>   service android:name=".GCMIntentService"

This intent service will be called by the GCMBroadcastReceiver (which is is provided by GCM library), as shown in the next step. It must be a subclass of `com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService`, must contain a public constructor, and should be named `my_app_package.GCMIntentService` (unless you use a subclass of `GCMBroadcastReceiver` that overrides the method used to name the service).

However, I can't subclass `com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService`, the import can't be resolved. How do I fix this?

Comment: do you have gcm.jar in your build path?

Comment: thanks, this is the answer, I put those jar files in my class folder but didn't add to build path.

Answer (score 12):

You have to install the libraries: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html#libs

> From the SDK Manager, install Extras > Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library. This creates a gcm directory under YOUR_SDK_ROOT/extras/google/ containing these subdirectories: gcm-client, gcm-server, samples/gcm-demo-client, samples/gcm-demo-server, and samples/gcm-demo-appengine.

Comment: sometimes, after Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library is installed, the problem persists. You have to manually add `gcm.jar` to Build Path

Comment: Google Cloud Messaging is Deprecated ! it's Google Play Service now

Comment: @Kimo_do do u have any idea what should i be using rather than com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService

Answer (score 1):

Download `gcm.jar` from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgcmjar.htm) and place it in `YOUR_PROJECT/app/libs` directory
 and then add `compile files('libs/gcm.jar')` line in `build.gradle` file