# I have GCM class error when i import eclipse project to Android studio

Tags: android

**I have `GCMBaseIntentService`  error.This issue create when I import project Eclipse to Android Studio**

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService
```

**Here are dependencies I add a lot of dependencies but issue not resolved**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.totalsoft.thearena"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-   android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.1'
    compile files('libs/acra.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.45.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.45.jar')
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'

    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.2.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'

}
```

Comment: Are there any error messages showing up?

Comment: yes GCMIntentService cannot extends with GCMBaseIntentService

Answer (score 1):

`GCMIntentService` is already deprecated. From this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/google/iosched/issues/51), it will direct you to [Android Developer's Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/09/conference-data-sync-gcm-google-io.html) where it is mentioned:

> ...the GCMBaseIntentService class has been deprecated. Please use the [GoogleCloudMessaging API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging) instead.

If you still want to try and proceed with the implementation that you already have. You can refer to this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183240/cannot-resolve-com-google-android-gcm-gcmbaseintentservice-android-studio). It would seem that since the `GCMIntentService` has been deprecated, it is no longer included in the Play Services library. From the post:

> After lot of google I found that this class is not in google_play_service library but it is in gcm.jar which is deprecated now. I dont know why google has given link to old code and explained latest code in the document.

Where to find a gcm.jar file? That, I'm not sure. Found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11472638/4625829) that might help you though. But seeing that it's been years since it was answered, I suggest you just use the new `GoogleCloudMessaging API`.

Cheers! :D